# Create an empty array column of certain type in pyspark DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I try to add to a df a column with an empty array of arrays of strings, but I end up adding a column of arrays of strings.

I tried this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = df.withColumn('newCol', F.array([]))
```

How can I do this in pyspark?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Another way to achieve an empty array of arrays column:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = df.withColumn('newCol', F.array(F.array()))
```

Because `F.array()` defaults to an array of strings type, the `newCol` column will have type `ArrayType(ArrayType(StringType,false),false)`. If you need the inner array to be some type other than string, you can cast the inner `F.array()` directly as follows.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T
int_array_type = T.ArrayType(T.IntegerType())  # "array<integer>" also works
df = df.withColumn('newCol', F.array(F.array().cast(int_array_type)))
```

In this example, `newCol` will have a type of `ArrayType(ArrayType(IntegerType,true),false)`.

Answer (score 8):

This is one of the way:

```
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as F
>>> myList = [('Alice', 1)]
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(myList)
>>> df.schema
StructType(List(StructField(_1,StringType,true),StructField(_2,LongType,true)))
>>> df = df.withColumn('temp', F.array()).withColumn("newCol", F.array("temp")).drop("temp")
>>> df.schema
StructType(List(StructField(_1,StringType,true),StructField(_2,LongType,true),StructField(newCol,ArrayType(ArrayType(StringType,false),false),false)))
>>> df
DataFrame[_1: string, _2: bigint, newCol: array<array<string>>]
>>> df.collect()
[Row(_1=u'Alice', _2=1, newCol=[[]])]
```